# Dart Editor Visual Theme...editable?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

The new visual theme picker is awesome! Thank you! We can finally "dim the lights". Although, black and, specially, blue fonts, on a dark background, are hard on the eyes. Is there some sort of editable CSS like file that we can tune?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is to look in the files in this folder:

```
plugins\com.google.dart.tools.deploy_0.2.8.r15948\themes
```

(where `r15948` is the version of the editor)

This contains a series of xml files - one per theme, where you can edit the relevant color values.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Preferences >> Visual Theme, it says:

Download more themes or create your own on eclipsecolorthemes.org. It also lets you import themes.

Comment: Thank you...I did see that more themes could be imported. It's really too much to ask, and my sound a bit selfish, but I wish the theme would change automatically between Dart, HTML, and CSS files...lol. I'm going to try to edit the "plugins\com.google.dart.tools.deploy_0.2.8.r15948\themes" file. Thanks agian.

Answer (score 1):

Hannes Rammer built an open source tool for this

- https://github.com/HannesRammer/Rainbow (GitHub)
- http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rainbow

also available online at 
https://rainbow-dart.appspot.com/